# save_post action doesn't passing post id to my function as argument

Tags: theme-development, actions, save-post

I'm adding a box to *add / update post screen*.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'psd_upload_kaydet' );
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'psd_upload' );
function psd_upload()
{
    add_meta_box("psd-upload", "Bir Dosya Upload Edin", "psd_upload_box", "post");
}
function psd_upload_box($post)
{
    echo "content here";
}
function psd_upload_kaydet($post_id)
{
    die($post_id); // for debugging, i'll explain it
}
```

There is no error while adding box, but normally, when post saved, `add_action( 'save_post', 'psd_upload_kaydet' );` will pass **post id** as an argument to `psd_upload_kaydet()`

But it's not passing post it to `psd_upload_kaydet()` as an argument. I'm checking it `die($post_id);` , but it's returning just blank page.

In shortly, I need **post id** in `psd_upload_kaydet()` :)

Answer (score 3):

`die` is an alias of `exit` and from php.net:

> void **exit** ([ string *$status* ] )
>
> If status is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status
>   and not printed.

Try doing the following instead.

```
function psd_upload_kaydet($post_id)
{
    echo $post_id;
    die(); // for debugging, i'll explain it
}
```

edit.

Comment: die()'s parameter will be printed to page : http://codepad.viper-7.com/tA5Zsn

Comment: I will not flame you for down voting my correct answer. Instead I will just assume you missed the part where I said **integers** are **not** printed. http://codepad.viper-7.com/wgrBDB

Comment: I vote down, because i'm trying die($post_id . " error"); and still getting error. I'll try it again. I'll clear downvote if you edit answer.

Comment: There is no need for me to edit my answer because it is correct. die($post_id . "error") will work too. If it doesn't, then you have a problem somewhere else. I'm down voting this question as it is a PHP issue not a WordPress issue, and should therefore be asked on stackoverflow.

Comment: NO you misunderstood. I down voted you and now i can't change my vote to up, if you don't edit your answer. I'm getting : **Your vote is now locked in
unless this answer is edited** error . So, please edit your answer, for example just add a new blank line to your answer :)

Comment: Oh, I apologize. My answer is edited, edit yours and I will reverse mine too. Did you get this to work?

Comment: yes, up voted..